# Replaying http traffic using gor / nginx(post_action) shows broken pipe error in tomcat logs

Tags: http, tomcat, nginx

We are trying to replay live HTTP Production traffic to Pre-Prod environment using GOR / Nginx(post_action / mirror). 
For the GET Requests we see the below error :

```
2017-09-14 11:56:30 ERROR [DataProviderController.getData] au.gov.nsw.transport.gtfs.controller.DataProviderController:136
ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:438)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:426)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:84)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.write(IOUtils.java:631)
        at au.gov.nsw.transport.gtfs.controller.DataProviderController.getData(DataProviderController.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at au.gov.nsw.transport.gtfs.filter.VersionHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(VersionHeaderFilter.java:60)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:123)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:163)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:242)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:213)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:268)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:93)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter$FakeOutputStream.write(GzipOutputFilter.java:177)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.FlushableGZIPOutputStream.deflate(FlushableGZIPOutputStream.java:153)
        at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:145)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.FlushableGZIPOutputStream.write(FlushableGZIPOutputStream.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.doWrite(GzipOutputFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:192)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:520)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:408)
        ... 62 more
```

The error says that the clientaborted the connection. However, when we attempt to do a similar get request using wget(every second), the error does not show in the logs. 
We are not sure if we need to set a timeout or if there is any directive for NGINX or switch for GOR.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Take nginx out of picture and try to see if you can directly replicate traffic to tomcat. Try to isolate the problem causing component in this case

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?